# Excel VBA to split / format data vertically

Tags: excel

I am trying to format and split a column of excel cells vertically.  Each cell contains starts ICD-10: and then lots of codes separated with commas ",".  I would like to Removed the ICD-10: and all of the spaces resulting in a column of just the individual codes.  I found the following VBA code and have modified it to partly.  I need to help removing the unwanted spaces and "ICD-10:" from the out put.  I tried using trim and replace but I don't have a super firm understanding of exactly how this is working I just know it is close.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
Sub splitvertically()
'updatebyExtendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xOutArr As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xOutRg = Application.InputBox("please select output cell:", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xOutRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each xCell In xRg
        If xStr = "" Then
            xStr = xCell.Value
        Else
            xStr = xStr & "," & xCell.Value
        End If
    Next
    xOutArr = VBA.Split(xStr, ",")
    xOutRg.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(xOutArr) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xOutArr)
    
End Sub
```

Sample Data

A1 = ICD-10: S7291XB, I4891, S0101XA, S7291XB, Z7901, V0300XA

A2 = ICD-10: S72431C, D62, E0590, E43, E785, E872, F321, G4700, I129, I2510, I441, I4891, I4892, I959, N183, R339, S0101XA, S01111A, S32591A, S7010XA, S72431C, Z6823, Z7901, Z87891, Y92481, S72351B

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a very good beginning.  With only 3 more lines of code, we can make it happen.  I don't know what happens then the output range xOutRg is more than one cell.

```
Option Explicit ' ALWAYS

Sub splitvertically()
'updatebyExtendoffice
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xOutRg As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim xTxt As String
    Dim xStr As String
    Dim xOutArr As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    xTxt = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("please select the data range:", "Kutools for Excel", xTxt, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xOutRg = Application.InputBox("please select output cell:", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , 8)
    If xOutRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each xCell In xRg
        
        'just get the input value(s), then remove ICD-10, then remove any spaces
        xTxt = xCell.Value
        xTxt = Replace(xTxt, "ICD-10:", "")
        xTxt = Replace(xTxt, " ", "")
        
        ' then append xTxt (not original cell)
        If xStr = "" Then
            xStr = xTxt
        Else
            xStr = xStr & "," & xTxt
        End If
    Next
    xOutArr = VBA.Split(xStr, ",")
    xOutRg.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(xOutArr) + 1, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(xOutArr)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like what I was trying to do. Modifying xTxt is the key I was missing. I will give this a shot first thing in the AM. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that will split the cells in the way you describe. It works very fast but please take the time to read all the comments carefully. Some of them are just informative but others may require your action. In this regard, pay attention to the names I have given to the variables. A name like `FirstDataRow` will help you know what you should adjust.

```
Sub SplitCellsToList()

    Const FirstDataRow As Long = 2          ' change to suit
    Const InputColumn As Long = 1           ' change to suit (1 = column A)
    
    Dim OutCell         As Range            ' first cell of output list
    Dim InArr           As Variant          ' array of input values
    Dim OutArr          As Variant          ' array of output values
    Dim n               As Long             ' row index of OutArr
    Dim Sp()            As String           ' Split cell value
    Dim i               As Integer          ' index of Split
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: sheet rows
    
    Set OutCell = Sheet1.Cells(2, "D")      ' change to suit
    With ActiveSheet
        InArr = .Range(.Cells(FirstDataRow, InputColumn), _
                       .Cells(.Rows.Count, InputColumn).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    
    ReDim OutArr(1 To 5000)                 ' increase if required
    ' 5000 is a number intended to be larger by a significant margin
    ' than the total number of codes expected in the output
    
    For R = 1 To UBound(InArr)
        Sp = Split(InArr(R, 1), ":")
        If UBound(Sp) Then
            Sp = Split(Sp(1), ",")
            For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
                Sp(i) = Trim(Sp(i))
                If Len(Sp(i)) Then
                    n = n + 1
                    OutArr(n) = Sp(i)
                End If
            Next i
        Else
            ' leave the string untreated if no colon is found in it
            n = n + 1
            OutArr(n) = InArr(R, 1)
        End If
    Next R
    
    If n Then
        ReDim Preserve OutArr(1 To n)
        OutCell.Resize(n).Value = Application.Transpose(OutArr)
    End If
End Sub
```